# How to test the model with Minitest & no database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I am using **rails 4.2.1 & ruby 2.2.1** in my appliation. So minitest is automatically added which is of version **5.1**. There is no database in my application.
With database I am able to test the model. How do I test the model without database?

I have created a user model:

```
class User
  include ActiveModel::Model
end
```

users.yml:

```
one:
  firstName: Avi
  email: a@a.a
```

user_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase      
  test "the truth" do 
    user = users(:one)
    assert true
  end
end
```

Here I am getting the error: `Undefined methods users`. I am getting proper data if daabase exists.
I even tried adding `include ActiveModel::Lint::Tests` still getting the same error.
Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The class `ActiveSupport::TestCase` expects that a database connection is active. You probably want to switch that to `Minitest::Test`, but that means that you can't use the `users` fixture method to retrieve a record from the database.

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_sanity
    user = User.new
    user.first_name = "Avi"
    user.email = "a@a.a"
    assert user
  end
end
```

Comment: Slightly trickier, I'm finding. You need to manually import minitest, rather than the default *rails/test_help* in your *test_helper.rb*... Will report more when I've got it sorted...